# More efficient way to create frequency column based on different groupings

Tags: r, efficiency, dplyr

I have code below that calculates a frequency for each column element (respective to it's own column) and adds all five frequencies together in a column. The code works but is very slow and the majority of the processing time is spent on this process. Any ideas to accomplish the same goal but more efficiently?

````
Create_Freq <- function(Word_List) {

 library(dplyr)
 
 Word_List$AvgFreq <- (Word_List%>% add_count(FirstLet))[,"n"] +
                      (Word_List%>% add_count(SecLet))[,"n"] +
                      (Word_List%>% add_count(ThirdtLet))[,"n"] +
                      (Word_List%>% add_count(FourLet))[,"n"] +
                      (Word_List%>% add_count(FifthLet))[,"n"]

 return(Word_List)
}

```
````

Comment: Please post a sample data with ```dput()``` so that we can replicate the problem.